# How to use Pug in Nuxt 3.x?

Tags: nuxt.js, pug, vite, nuxtjs3

If we create the Nuxt 3 application by `npx nuxi init nuxt3-app` and change the content of `app.vue` from

```xml
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtWelcome />
  </div>
</template>
```

to

```
<template lang="pug">

  div
    NuxtWelcome

</template>
```

we'll get

```
 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] Cannot find module 'pug'                                                                                                                                                                                                      17:05:54
Require stack:
- D:\IntelliJ IDEA\Experiments\nuxt3-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js
- D:\IntelliJ IDEA\Experiments\nuxt3-app\node_modules\vue\compiler-sfc\index.js
- D:\IntelliJ IDEA\Experiments\nuxt3-app\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-vue\dist\index.js
```

I did not expected the build-in Pug support but there is also no hint how to provide.

AFAIK default Nuxt 3 setup use the Vite istead of Webpack. Maybe the answer is in Vite setup overriding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Vite:

1. Install [vite-plugin-pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pug). Vite detects it automatically.
2. Restart the application building

And be careful with [this bug](https://github.com/yyx990803/pug-plain-loader/issues/18).

Comment: If you're taking the Pug path, be careful of a lot of bugs actually because when you add a middleware between your HTML and your code, you will have some issues at some point.

Comment: Also, please accept this answer.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for the comment! I will accept this answer once Stack Overflow will permit it (own answers could be accepted in 3 days).

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been over a year since this question, but I recently had the same question and found an easier solution.

You can just install `pug` and it will work. No need for any plugins or other extra configs.

Just in case: I am using `Nuxt@3.6.5` and `Pug@3.0.2`

UPD: There is actually a need for a little bit of config. Mainly for IDE support. You should also add `@vue/language-plugin-pug` and extend your `tsconfig.json` with `vueCompilerOptions` like it shown below:

```json
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@vue/language-plugin-pug"]
  }
}
```

Comment: you can include this in `eslintrc` to IDE support `{
  "extends": [
    "@nuxt/eslint-config",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:vue-pug/vue3-recommended"
  ]
}`